# passing derived object as base class reference parameter

Tags: c++, dynamic-binding

This examples shows a derived class object being passed to a function which takes reference to base class as the parameter. Member function `g(int)` in the derived class hides the `g(float)` in the base class. I understand that and my question is not related to it.

```
class Base {
public:
    virtual void g(float x) throw()
    {
        cout << "Base::g(float)\n";
    }
};

class Derived : public Base {
public:        
    virtual void g(int x) throw() // Bad: Hides Base::g(float)
    {
        cout << "Derived::g(int)\n";
    }
};


void sampleTwo(Base& b, Derived& d)
{
    b.g(3.14f);
    d.g(3.14f); // Bad: Converts 3.14 to 3 and calls Derived::g(int)
}

int main()
{
    Derived d;
    sampleTwo(d, d);
    return 0;
}
```

Output is:

```
Base::g(float)
Derived::g(int)
```

My question is with the output "Base::g(float)".  Since the object referenced by 'b' in sampleTwo() is derived object, shouldn't the dynamic binding call the g() method of the derived class (converting float to int) ?

Comment: When writing a derived class's function to override a base class's virtual, it's a great idea to start using the `override` keyword (assuming a compiler with reasonable C++11 support). That way the compiler can give you an error if the function doesn't actually override as you intended.

Comment: I am also surprised, but my initial guess would have been to see base::g(float) called twice, not derived::g(int), since the function call in both cases matches the signature of g(float), which is a different function that g(int) (these are two different functions, your code does not make any overriding)

Comment: You should do `using Base::g` in `Derived` to unhide `Base::g(float)`.

Answer (score 4):

`g(int)` and `g(float)` are two completely different methods. `Derived::g(int)` does not override `Base::g(float)`. These methods are unrelated.

Since `Derived` does not override `g(float)`, your expectations about `b.g(3.14f)` are unfounded. As expected, `b.g(3.14f)` should call `Base::g(float)`.

If you override `g(float)` in `Derived`, then `b.g(3.14f)` will indeed call `Derived::g(float)`.

Answer (score 1):

Dynamic dispatch invokes the final overrider. Since `Derived::g` hides rather than overrides `Base::g`, the final overrider of `Base::g` in `Derived` is still `Base::g`.

Answer (score 0):

`g(float)` and `g(int)` are different function members.  If you want `Derived` to work, you have to use `g(float)` in both classes.

`g()` can be overloaded check out function overloading:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_overloading

Example (`g(float)` and `g(int)` in the same class and separate functions):

```
class Derived : public Base {
public:

    void g(float x) throw();
    void g(int x) throw();

};
```